# PyCharm error: kivy.garden.knob import successfully but not active on Script

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I've tried continuous time to run https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.knob "example.kv" file and "example.py" file.In order to implement knob into my project. Unfortunately, I can't run the above example code due to imported knob file don't active in my python script.

**Edit:** After installing virtualenv and activating the script  I'm running the python script recognizing the import file but giving me with below error?

**Error:**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" C:/Users/karannchat/PycharmProjects/knob/main.py 
[INFO   ] [Logger     ] Record log in C:\Users\karannchat\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-03-13_19.txt 
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1 
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] 
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded  

Traceback (most recent call last):    
   File "C:/Users/karannchat/PycharmProjects/knob/main.py", line 3, in <module>
         from kivy.garden.knob import  Knob     
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load    
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked    
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked    
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 640, in
    _load_backward_compatible  KeyError: 'kivy.garden.knob'
```

---

```
<Main>
GridLayout:
    pos: root.pos
    size: root.size
    cols: 3
    spacing: 100
    padding: 50

    Knob:
        min:4
        max:5
        size: 200, 200
        value: 0
        show_marker: True
        knobimg_source: "img/knob_metal.png"
        show_marker: False

    Knob:
        size: 200, 200
        value: 0
        show_marker: True
        knobimg_source: "img/knob_metal.png"
        marker_img: "img/bline.png"
        markeroff_color: 0.3, 0.3, .3, 1

    Knob:
        size: 200, 200
        value: 0
        show_marker: True
        knobimg_source: ""
        knobimg_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
        marker_img: "img/bline.png"
        markeroff_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
        marker_inner_color: 0, 0, 0, 1

    Knob:
        size: 200, 200
        value: 0
        show_marker: True
        knobimg_source: "img/knob_metal.png"
        marker_img: "img/bline.png"
        markeroff_color: 0.0, 0.0, .0, 1
        knobimg_size: 0.7

    Knob:
        size: 200, 200
        step: 25
        value: 10
        show_marker: True
        knobimg_source: "img/knob_metal.png"
        marker_img: "img/bline2.png"
        markeroff_img: "img/bline2_off.png"
        markeroff_color: 0.3, 0.3, .3, 1
        marker_ahead: 6
        knobimg_size: 0.8
        marker_startangle: 6

    Knob:
        size: 200, 200
        value: 0
        knobimg_source: "img/knob_black.png"
        markeroff_color: 0.0, 0.0, .0, 1
        knobimg_size: 0.9
        marker_img: "img/bline3.png"
```

---

```
from kivy.base  import  runTouchApp
from kivy.lang  import  Builder
from kivy.garden.knob import  Knob # <<---- this is not active in the code hence i can't run the code 

# LOAD KV UIX
runTouchApp(Builder.load_file('main.kv'))
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using `virtualenv`??

Comment: @PS1212  I wasn't but after seen your comment have   run "pip install virtualenv"  and "pip install virtualenvwrapper-win" (based on http://timmyreilly.azurewebsites.net/python-pip-virtualenv-installation-on-windows/ instruction) no luck though!!

Comment: I think it's a bug, I recommend reporting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

Maybe missing a folder, `__pycache__` and a module, e.g. `__init__.cpython-37` in folder, *Windows 10: `C:\Users\usr\.kivy\garden\garden.knob`* (Replace *`usr`* with your username) or  *Xubuntu / Linux: `~/.kivy/garden/garden.knob`*.

## Solution

### Windows 10

1. List all the garden packages installed using `garden list` at Command Prompt or Windows Powershell.
2. *`cd Users\usr\.kivy\garden\garden.knob`*
3. *`python -m py_compile __init__.py`* which should create the missing folder and module.

### Xubuntu / Linux

1. List all the garden packages installed using `garden list` at Terminal Emulator.
2. *`cd ~/.kivy/garden/garden.knob`*
3. *`python3 -m py_compile __init__.py`* which should create the missing folder and module.

Exit and relaunch PyCharm IDE.

[image: Missing folder, __pycache__]
[image: Missing module, __init__.cpython-37]

## Example

No problem running Kivy garden.knob on the following environments using PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5:

- Xubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver, Kivy 1.10.1 & 1.11.0-dev, Python 3.6, and Python 2
- Windows 10 Home, Kivy 1.10.1, and Python 3.7.2

## Output

[image: Kivy Garden Knob - Windows 10, Python 3]
[image: Kivy Garden Knob - Xubuntu 18.04, Python 3]
[image: Kivy Garden Knob - Xubuntu 18.04, Python 2]

Comment: Hi ikolim , really appreciate your well-instructed answer. As you mentioned __pycache__ folder was missing in my downloaded file from  https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.knob.So last two hours here what i did; 1.I look at my C:\Users\karannchat\.kivy folder but couldn't find __pycache__ folder only icon/logs and mods folder (see next comment)

Comment: 2.so I went to C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\garden folder find __pycache__ folder with _init__ file (that all have in there) 3. i thought then you want me to create a __pycache__ folder inside my downloaded file from git. hence I cd C:\Users\karannchat\Downloads\garden.knob-master\garden.knob-master and run python -m py_compile __init__.py via Command Prompt which created the missing file. but my " from kivy.garden.knob import  Knob" inactive in the script. (bit of burnout right now tbh) any help appreciated.. cheers!!

Comment: Step 1) Open a Command Prompt or Windows Powershel windowl. Step 2) Change directory by typing `cd C:\Users\karannchat\.kivy\garden\garden.knob` Step 3) Compile `__init__.py` by executing, `python -m py_compile __init__.py` This will creates the missing file; relaunch PyCharm and run your Kivy App.

Answer (score 0):

I know its an extremely old post and you might have solved the query by now but anyways.

1. Go to 'C:\Users(your user name)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\kivy\garden'
2. Make a folder knob and paste the file **init**.py from garden.knob-master(your github folder)
3. Make the **pycache** folder as Mr. Ikolim said
4. Delete **pycache** and  **init**.py files from garden.knob-master(your github folder)
5. Open garden.knob-master(your github folder) as project in Pycharm
6. Run example.py